# How to let SQL Server not return null query?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a sql query like this:

```
if table1 exist
    if table1 has data
       select * from table1

if table2 exist
    if table2 has data
       select * from table2
...
tableN
```

then I iterate dataset in c#
but even a table does not exist in database, there is an empty result table in dataset, How to write the sql to only return not empty queries? say I have 10 tables, 3 not exist in database, So, only 7 result tables in returned dataset?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what "but even a table does not exist in database, there is an empty table in database" means; do you mean a table that has no rows? Or are you comparing the database and (for example) the resulting `DataSet`?

Comment: It isn't very common that you need to worry about *existence* of individual tables; generally, this would mean (to me) that your install script has failed... in particular, most RDBMS can't really optimise for the case where tables may or may not be there, since they can't cache an execution plan for a missing table.

Or are you talking about the case where the tables exists but is empty?

Comment: @Marc Gravell sorry， I meant “there is an empty table with no cols and rows in returned dataset ”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I meant "there is an empty table with no cols and rows in returned dataset"

ahh... so you want the missing table to have a stub in your `DataSet`? Seems pretty... oddd - but I guess you could do something like:

```
if object_id('table2') is not null -- yeuch yeuch yeuch (see below)
begin
    select * from table2
end
else
begin
    select 1 where 1 = 0 
end
```

Again, I stress that I find this desire... unusual; but:

- if we `select` even if there isn't data, we just get an empty table, which is fine
- if the table doesn't exist, we just get a 1-column, 0-row stub

There are better ways of checking for existance of an object - for example, checking the info-schema tables; but I'm still not convinced that it is (in the general case) *sensible* to be overly concerned about existence / non-existence of tables, unless you're:

- writing *tooling*, such as a query analyzer or ORM tool
- writing a data impoty utility that can't trust ad-hoc data

Answer (score 0):

You can easily extract details about each table available in your Database:

```
use MyDBName
go

select * from sys.tables
go
```

Using a cursor (though I personally avoid them if at all possible), you could loop through and build your queries dynamically to use only the tables available, meaning you won't return any NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty hard to guess without knowing what kind of database - especially the involved entities and relations - you are talking about...
And as said before, you would'nt normally check if a table exists beforehand - it sounds to me like a question of persistence...